# CodeIgniter and GIT: What not to check-in?

Tags: git, codeigniter, xampp

This is my first attempt with CodeIgniter and I'm trying to figure out how to configure it against a GIT repo. The basic idea here is to avoid checking-in framework files and somehow keep only my work in GIT. What is the default/best practice here. Do people commit entire codeigniter folder into source control? Looking at the default `.gitignore` file, it doesn't look like they want to exclude framework folders like `system` and `user_guide` etc.

My idea is to keep XAMPP and CodeIgnitor in default location (`c:\xampp`) and keep my code in source code in, say `D:\My Projects\NewExcitingWebsite` (with `models`, `views` and `controllers` folders therein) and then redirect codeigniter to look towards that folder by setting variables in config files. Is that the correct way to go? If yes, how do I set path for `Controllers`? There is a variable for `views` folder that can be set, but none for controllers and models.

Comment: A look at [gitignore.io](https://gitignore.io/) may also provide some hints. The rules there seem rather fine grained so it might be worth checking if any of them cover special cases that one might have missed.

Comment: @mmlr: Thanks. Pretty similar to the default `.gitignore`. This one too is not excluding `system` and `user_guide`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My practice is to track the entire framework except `user_guide`, `application/cache` and `application/logs`.

Tracking `system/` is helpful because when CI has updates from they usually amount to simply replacing `system/` and its contents. Nice to have commits available should you need to revert to a prior version of CI.

GIT repositories are so light weight it's hardly worth the effort to segregate files as you describe. I have a CI repo that's about six years old containing a huge number of commits representing tens of thousands of changes and multiple versions of CI. The size of the .git folder is about 39MB. That's a trivially small file for a modern computer. Checking out any given branch or reverting a commit happens in seconds.

Regarding CI's file structure. The folders inside `application/` (controllers, models, libraries, etc.) more or less require that relationship. The `views` folder is an exception and can be in a non-standard location. Same with `application` and `system` folders. The file `index.php` can be edited to change where those folders are to be found and even what they are named.

To change where `controllers` live you would have to extend (or hack) the `CI_Loader` class. Not impossible but hardly worth the effort.